# angular2 rc5 using component from feature module not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular2-components, angular2-ngmodel

I have an app module and a feature module. A component called "AudioPlayerComponent" is declared in the feature module. I want to use it in the app module, but its not showing. No errors.

Am I missing something?

**App Module:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule, 
    ReciterModule, // the feature module which has the audio player
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    AudioPlayerService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**Feature Module:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    reciterRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    ReciterDetailComponent, 
    WidgetComponent,
    AudioPlayerComponent  // this is the component I want to also use in the app component
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    RecitersService 
  ]
})
```

**A component in the feature module that uses audio-player (Shows)**

```
<div class="reciter-detail">
   ...
    <audio-player></audio-player>

</div>
```

App component that tries to use audio-player  (doesn't show):

```
<nav-main></nav-main> 
 <div class="container">

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>


    <audio-player></audio-player>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `AudioPlayerComponent` in the exports of Feature Module.

If you want to use any Component, Pipe, Directive from Feature Module into another module you need to export them

```
  @NgModule({
   imports: [
     CommonModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
     reciterRouting
    ],
   declarations: [
     ReciterDetailComponent, 
     WidgetComponent,
     AudioPlayerComponent  // this is the component I want to also use in the app component
   ],
   //add exports
   exports: [ 
      AudioPlayerComponent
   ],
   providers: [
     AppService,
     RecitersService 
   ]
  })
```

Read more about NgModule properties [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#ngmodule-properties).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. I ended reading the guide and making a separate shared module.

**Shared Module:**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [
        AudioPlayerComponent
    ],
    exports: [ 
        AudioPlayerComponent,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [AppService,AudioPlayerService]
        };
    }
}
```

**App Module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule, 
    ReciterModule,
    routing, 
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Feature Module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    HttpModule,
    reciterRouting,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ReciterDetailComponent, 
    WidgetComponent 
  ],
  providers: [ 
    RecitersService 
  ],
  exports: [ReciterDetailComponent]
})
```